# Android Hilt UninitializedPropertyAccessException when @Inject by @Provides inherited subclass

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, inject

I am using hilt in my android app project

And I am trying to inject inherited subclass using @Provides and @Inject like below...

But Always there is a UninitializedPropertyAccessException issue

Is there any wrong way to using Hilt on my code?(https://github.com/woosuk0410/MyHilt)

I have a alternative solution using factory to resolve it but if possible i want to use @Provides

I'd appreciate if you could help

Thanks

```
@Singleton
class Engine @Inject constructor() { 
    fun accel()  {
        Log.e("SAMPLE", "engine accel")
    }
}


@Singleton
open class Car @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var engine: Engine
    fun accel() {
        engine.accel()
    }
}

@Singleton
class ElectricCar @Inject constructor() : Car()

@Singleton
class GasolineCar @Inject constructor() : Car() 

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object ModuleProvides {
    @Provides
    fun getCar() :Car {
        return if(true) // some condition
             ElectricCar()
        else
            GasolineCar()
    }
}

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var car: Car
    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: AlternativeCarFactory
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        //this works fine
//        val altCar = factory.getInstance()
//        altCar.accel()

        // this always makes UninitializedPropertyAccessException a
        car.accel()
    }
}

@Singleton
class AlternativeCarFactory @Inject constructor() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var electricCar: ElectricCar
    @Inject
    lateinit var gasolineCar: GasolineCar
    fun getInstance(): Car {
         return if (true) electricCar else gasolineCar
    }
}
```

Comment: Your Car should be independent of engine. Car implementation(ElectricCar, GasolineCar) class should pass engine value to car class.  Bcoz Electric & Gasoline car engine are diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

Car Class

```
open class Car @Inject constructor(private val engine: Engine) {

    fun accel() {
        engine.accel()
    }
}
```

Electric Car

```
@Singleton
class ElectricCar @Inject constructor(private  val engine: Engine) : Car(engine){
}
```

Gasoline Car

```
@Singleton
class GasolineCar @Inject constructor(private val engine: Engine) : Car(engine) {
}
```

Module Provide

```
@Provides
fun getCar(engine: Engine): Car {
    return if (true) // some condition
        ElectricCar(engine)
    else
        GasolineCar(engine)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the circular dependency issue:
To inject `Car` in `mainActivity` Hilt uses `getCar` in `ModuleProvides` so it needs to create instance of `ElectricCar` But `ElectricCar` itself inherits from `Car` so **again** it needs to create `Car` instances.
It gets stuck in circular injection to create instances of `Car`!
There is many ways to solve this problem such as your second solution or this simple solution:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
    val car: Car get() = if(true) // some condition
             ElectricCar()
        else
             GasolineCar()
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        car.accel()
    }
}
```